# How to insert in every second row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I have a `DataFrame` which looks like this:

```
  c1 c2 
0  a  b  
1  c  d  
2  e  f  
3  g  h
```

I need to convert it to this one:

```
  c1 
0  a   
1  b   
2  c   
3  d
4  e
...
```

I know how to get all the values from the second column:

```
second_col_items = [df[['1']].iloc[i].item() for i in range(0,len(df.index))]
```

But I'm stuck on inserting. I need to insert rows in loop, and, moreover, I need to insert new rows between the existing ones. Is it even possible?

So, my question is: how to iterate through the list (`second_col_items` in my case) and insert it's values to every second row in `DataFrame`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `stack()` method:

source DF

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  c1 c2
0  a  b
1  c  d
2  e  f
3  g  h
```

stacked

```
In [3]: df.stack()
Out[3]:
0  c1    a
   c2    b
1  c1    c
   c2    d
2  c1    e
   c2    f
3  c1    g
   c2    h
dtype: object
```

stacked + reset_index

```
In [4]: df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[4]:
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
7    h
dtype: object

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 5):

You can unwind with `ravel` or `flatten`.  Both are `numpy` methods that can be applied the the `values` attribute of a `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series`

***solution***

```
pd.Series(df.values.ravel(), name='c1')

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
7    h
Name: c1, dtype: object
```

Or

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(c1=df.values.ravel())

  c1
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
5  f
6  g
7  h
```

---

***naive time test***

[image]

Comment: Is it faster? can you add timings?